# Why is this administration page cached?

Tags: caching, routes

I created a group entity which has a tab 'Pending memberships'. This page callback does a database query which retrieves the pending memberships and renders the usernames in an item list, along with an 'Approve' link next to each item. The link maps via a menu item (obviously) to this function:

```
function group_user_approve_callback($user, $group) {
  // Update db record, sets membership to approved
  group_user_approve_membership($user->uid, $group->gid);

  $user = user_load($user->uid);
  $group = group_load($group->gid);
  drupal_set_message(t('The pending membership of %username has been approved.', array('%username' => $user->name)));
  watchdog('group_user', 'Membership of %username to group %group_name approved.', array('%username' => $user->name, '%group_name' => $group->name));

  // Redirect to the exact same page    
  drupal_goto('group/' . $group->gid . '/pending_memberships');
}
```

The `drupal_goto()` function effectively reloads the page.

But somehow, the page is cached and it doesn't show the message and doesn't reflect the approval, since the user is still in the list. Only after clearing the cache, or switching pages, the page is updated.

What is causing this page to be cached?

Comment: Pages are never cached for authenticated users. I think that this is the entity that is cached in a way. Could you paste the callback that shows the list ?

Comment: The entity is not being displayed on this page, only a list of usernames with links next to it. This page is a subtab of the entity. Notice that the message also doesn't show up...